# Values not displaying in Forms 6i

Tags: plsql, oracleforms, formbuilder

I have a form that saves the values entered by the user. When clicking the save button, the data gets saved in the back end. Also these values get populated when I query in the form. What I want is all the saved values are to be displayed constantly when I query for this particular document. I have used COMMIT-FORM to save the details.

Comment: So commit_form makes the values disappear? Is there a clear_form hidden somewhere in a trigger?

Comment: nope. I checked. clear_form isn't there. In other forms I have, it is showing. Only in this form it is not. Can there be any other reasons ? pls do help

Comment: Check for `next_record` in the triggers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the values when you call that form, you must EXECUTE_QUERY in the WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE trigger.